# How to make Amazon Connect current call attributes available to Salesforce?

Tags: servicecloud, cti, call-center, amazon-connect-salesforce-cti

in our service center application we use Amazon Connect CTI (AC). We want to pass  a few attributes AC collects from the customer, such as phone number, consent, language etc. We are aware AC can pass them to Salesforce via record screenpops. However, in certain scenarios incoming call launches a screen flow where the agent can make choices before initiating a case or contact record.

Can AC current call attributes be made available to Salesforce, so Salesforce can pick them up when needed?

Alternatively, we thought storing incoming call attributes in a separate object each time there is an incoming call and querying it's records when needed. However, we couldn't figure out how to filter it for the exact record.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance that could steer us towards the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Attributes in the CTI Adapter record
See here, I'm getting 5 attributes (be careful it's case sensitive) and those attributes are available to see for the agent in the Attributes screen
[image: screenshot]

Any attributes you assign in AWS flow will be available to be used there

Refer to this documentation for more details:
https://amazon-connect.github.io/amazon-connect-salesforce-cti/docs/lightning/cti-adapter/02-cti-attributes

Comment: Attributes are only available in the Telephony app, however they are not accessible in any Salesforce context. 

We our final solution was to let Amazon Connect insert a custom object record in Salesforce each time an agent answers the call. We query those inserted records in a Flow to access the attributes we need.

I wish the attributes were available to Salesforce.